# Entity framework 7 (Core) + SQLite + Autofac

Tags: c#, sqlite, autofac

Register AddDbContext
Startup.cs -> ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)

```cs
services
    .AddEntityFrameworkSqlite()
    .AddDbContext<DB>((p, b) =>
        {
            b.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetSection("Data").GetSection("DefaultConnection").GetValue<string>("ConnectionString"));
        });
```

Register in Autofac

```cs
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.Populate(services);
```

Get in constructor (db not null)

```cs
public SomeClass(DB db)
{
    var db2 = new DB();
    var e1 = db2.Elements.FirstOrDefault(); //<-- WORK
    var e2 = db.Elements.FirstOrDefault(); //<-- Exception
}
```

Generate exception

**{System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object**

*How correct register EF7 SQLite with Autofac*?

Comment: What version of ASP Core are you running?

Comment: @johnny5 netcoreapp1.0, Autofac430, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc101

Comment: A lot has changed since then I'd try upgrading to 1.10 first